# Proving $\sum_{cyc} \frac{a(a^2+2bc)}{b+c}\ge \frac{{(a+b+c)}^2}{2}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

> Prove that (where $a,b,c>0$) $$\sum_{cyc} \frac{a(a^2+2bc)}{b+c}\ge \frac{{(a+b+c)}^2}{2}$$

I have found a proof for this problem but it is very lengthy and is not nice.(Its not using computer though).I shall post it later.

**Background**:
Here however is a very similar problem

> If $a,b,c>0$ then prove that $$\sum_{cyc} \frac{a(a^2+bc)}{b+c}\ge a^2+b^2+c^2$$

There is a beautiful proof of  this by Michael Rozenberg (arqady)

WLOG $a\ge b\ge c$ rewrite the inequality as $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a(a-b)(a-c)}{b+c}\ge 0$$ but  $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a(a-b)(a-c)}{b+c}\geq\frac{a(a-b)(a-c)}{b+c}+\frac{b(b-a)(b-c)}{a+c}=$$
$$=(a-b)(\frac{a(a-c)}{b+c}-\frac{b(b-c)}{a+c})\geq0$$

However this method doesnt work...

I am looking for a clean and smooth proof (without using BW,uvw or complete expanding)

I am not planning to disclose how I proved the inequality as it may spoil the fun!

Comment: What does cyc mean under the summation? Some kind of cyclic permutation? And if so of what?

Comment: @RobertTheTutor The cyc mean the summation over cyclic pernutations $a\to b\to c$ for example $$\sum_{cyc} a+2b=a+2b+b+2c+c+2a$$

Comment: I am sure this can be done by SOS or SOS - Schur. Personally, I don't consider $uvw$ method less aesthetic than SOS.

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore The desired inequality is written as $\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{a^3}{b+c} + 2abc\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}\frac{1}{b+c} \ge \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{2}$. The following is also true:  $\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{a^3}{b+c} + 2abc\frac{9}{2(a+b+c)} \ge \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{2}$ (C-S for the 2nd term in LHS).

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore I don't know if it helps for the pursuit of nice solutions.

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore  You have a solution, and you are pursuing a nice solution.

Comment: @RiverLi I didnt get your point? (sorry)

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore You said "I have found a proof for this problem but it is very lengthy and is not nice.(Its not using computer though)". If you can use BW, uvw, etc, there is a solution. Now, you want elegant/simple/neat/verynice solutions.

Comment: @RiverLi Ok got your point,I mean to say i dont mind if its a bit ugly ,Does mixed variables help here ? Thanks for your time by the way  my proof is not by BW

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Actually, I only use BW here. I have not yet gotten a nice solution.

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore By the way, for your question, the pqr expression is simple, i.e., we need to prove that $2p^4-9p^2q+15pr+4q^2\ge 0$.

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore I think it is not nice. So, wait for nice solutions.

Comment: @RiverLi sure  the inequality is equiavlent to $$2\color{red}{(p^4--5p^2q+4q^2+6pr)}+\color{blue}{p^2q+3pr-4q^2}\ge 0$$ which is true as its a combination of 4 the degree schur and the blue colored inequality is well known Thanks for your great observation

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore It is nice.

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore I think you should link solution of Michael Rozenberg here

Comment: @Buraian The solution I saw was in AOPS,I dont have the link anymore :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $c = \min\{a,b,c\},$ then
$$\sum \frac{a^3+abc}{b+c}-(a^2+b^2+c^2) = \frac{a(a-b)(a-c)}{b+c}+\frac{b(b-c)(b-a)}{c+a}+\frac{c(c-a)(c-b)}{a+b}$$
$$\geqslant \frac{a(a-b)(a-c)}{b+c}+\frac{b(b-c)(b-a)}{c+a} = \frac{(a-b)^2(a^2+ab+b^2-c^2)}{(b+c)(c+a)} \geqslant 0.$$
Therefore
$$\sum \frac{a^3+abc}{b+c} \geqslant a^2+b^2+c^2. \qquad (1)$$
Now, we write the inequality as
$$\sum \frac{a^3+abc}{b+c} + abc \sum \frac{1}{b+c} \geqslant \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{2}.$$
By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have
$$\sum \frac{1}{b+c} \geqslant \frac{9}{2(a+b+c)}. \qquad (2)$$
From $(1)$ and $(2),$ we need to prove
$$a^2+b^2+c^2+\frac{9abc}{2(a+b+c)} \geqslant \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{2},$$
equivalent to
$$a^2+b^2+c^2+\frac{9abc}{a+b+c} \geqslant 2(ab+bc+ca).$$
This is Schur inequality. The proof is completed.

Comment: Very nice nguyenhuyen_ag!Nice to see that you used the inequality I had kept as background Bravo!

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Thank you =))

Answer (score 3):

We want to show
$$
\sum_{cyc} \frac{a(a^2+2bc)}{b+c}\ge \frac{{(a+b+c)}^2}{2}
$$

The following steps mainly show how this inequality can be maximally simplified.
The final steps then have been proved by the OP Albus Dumbledore himself, and others.

Due to homogeneity, let $a+b+c =1$, then equivalently

$$
\sum_{cyc}  \frac{(a-1+1)(a^2+2bc)}{1-a} \ge \frac{1}{2} $$
$$-\sum_{cyc} (a^2+2bc) + \sum_{cyc} \frac{a^2+2bc}{1-a} \ge \frac{1}{2}$$
$$-(a+b+c)^2+ \sum_{cyc} \frac{a^2+2bc}{1-a} \ge \frac{1}{2}$$
$$\sum_{cyc} \frac{a^2-1+1+2bc}{1-a} \ge \frac{3}{2}
$$
$$-\sum_{cyc} (1+a)+\sum_{cyc} \frac{1+2bc}{1-a} \ge \frac{3}{2}
$$
$$\sum_{cyc} \frac{1+2bc}{b+c} \ge \frac{11}{2}
$$
Now we have
$$\frac{2bc}{1-a} =\frac{2bc}{b+c} = b+c -a-1  + \frac{1 -(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{b+c} $$
which leads to
$$(2 -(a^2+b^2+c^2))\sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{b+c} \ge \frac{15}{2}
$$
Now we have isolated a single sum, which is the main benefit of this answer.

This sum can be evaluated:
$$\sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{1-a} = \frac{3 -  (a^2+b^2+c^2)}{1 - 2abc - (a^2+b^2+c^2)}
$$
which leaves to show
$$(2 -(a^2+b^2+c^2))(3 -(a^2+b^2+c^2)) \ge \frac{15}{2} (1 - 2abc - (a^2+b^2+c^2))
$$
Let $x = a^2+b^2+c^2$ then we have to show
$$2x^2 + 5x + 30 abc \ge 3
$$

Note that by now, no single change has been made to the original question, since all transformations are equivalences.

The last inequality  can be proved (amongst other methods)  by Schur,  which has been done by the OP Albus Dumbledore himself, and others, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4023018/). $\qquad \Box$

Comment: +1 nice approach ,As I mentioned in question I had a proof ,I used the SOS method ,but this is slightly shorter and more elegant  Thank you very much (I now understand the mostivation of that question too :)